# Error in finding the matched ID

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Sheets sheet1, sheet2

With sheet1 i have id which always starts with 4, I look for this ID in sheet2, and pul the corresponding names and copy back to sheet1.

The ID is always 8 Digit Long.

during this , I have an Special case, where an ID has some Special charachters and charachters. eg: 41017734_dr_bad ; the code Fails in this case. I doesnot recognise the first 8 and Fails to paste in the another sheet.

Could someone suggest how to overcome this? 
I have an idea we could use whilcard and also strlen function. But struck how to use in code.

```
Sub match()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range, lstcl As Variant, lstcl2 As Variant, rgFnd As Variant
Dim n As Double, ID As String
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("P")
ID = "4"
lstcl = sh1.Range("N10000").End(xlUp).Row
lstcl2 = sh2.Range("L10000").End(xlUp).Row
'comparing columns N and L in both sheets
For Each cell In sh2.Range("L5:L" & lstcl2)
For n = 5 To lstcl
If cell = sh1.Range("N" & n) Then
'the cell in column M next to the matching cell is equal to the 4xxxxxxx number
cell.Offset(0, 1) = sh1.Range("N" & n)
'the next cell in column N is equal to the A2C number in column A
cell.Offset(0, 2) = cell.Offset(0, -11)
End If
Next
Next
'test that each cell in the first sheet corresponds to the located results in the second sheet _
'and pastes back the A2C number, using the Range.Find function
For Each cell2 In sh1.Range("N5:N" & lstcl)
If Left(cell2, 1) = ID Then
Set rgFnd = sh2.Range("M5:M" & lstcl2).Find(cell2.Value)
If Not rgFnd Is Nothing Then
cell2.Offset(0, 1) = sh2.Range(rgFnd.Address).Offset(0, 1)
End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image: this is how my ID Looks in sht1 in column N. It has ID with both B2C and ID starting with 4 (column N).]
[image: This is how the ID in sheet2 Looks like, with one column containing ID with B2C (column A) and another column contianining id with 4 (column L)]

[image: The result Looks like this, I look into the ID in column N and match them with column L in sheet2 which contains 4, and then i pull the corresponding ID from sheet2 and paste it to the next column. I have highlighted the spl condition as red, because if we notice the number is same, because of the charachters at the end, it is not recognized. I want to check for the first 8 Digit and if they match , then it should be able to do it as per the code below. It would be great, if we could add a line in my code and could get the result.]

Comment: Can you provide pictures of Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Comment: Why not fix the data before matching?

Comment: Please look up code indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub match()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range, lstcl As Variant, lstcl2 As Variant, rgFnd As Variant
    Dim n As Double, ID As String
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.sheets("S")
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.sheets("P")
    ID = "4"
    lstcl = sh1.Range("N10000").End(xlUp).Row
    lstcl2 = sh2.Range("L10000").End(xlUp).Row
    'comparing columns N and L in both sheets
    For Each cell In sh2.Range("L5:L" & lstcl2)
        For n = 5 To lstcl
            a = Left(sh1.Range("N" & n), 8)
            If cell = a Then
                'the cell in column M next to the matching cell is equal to the 4xxxxxxx number
                cell.Offset(0, 1) = a
                'the next cell in column N is equal to the A2C number in column A
                cell.Offset(0, 2) = cell.Offset(0, -11)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    'test that each cell in the first sheet corresponds to the located results in the second sheet _
    'and pastes back the A2C number, using the Range.Find function
    For Each cell2 In sh1.Range("N5:N" & lstcl)
        If Left(cell2, 1) = ID Then
            Set rgFnd = sh2.Range("M5:M" & lstcl2).Find(cell2.Value)
            If Not rgFnd Is Nothing Then
                cell2.Offset(0, 1) = sh2.Range(rgFnd.Address).Offset(0, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: THis is an formula , Could you tell me how i could do in VBA ?

Comment: and how i could have this line of code with in the above code.

Comment: @Mikz `Mid` is also vba.  It is used the same way, but the third criteria in vba is optional.

Comment: can you please share your sheet picture?i will help you on this

Comment: @ScottCraner I could then just include this in my above code and it works ?

Comment: @ Karthick Anbazhagan ya sure, i will do it

Comment: @KarthickAnbazhagan I have updated the post with Images

Comment: @KarthickAnbazhagan I am not getting any result now

Comment: @KarthickAnbazhagan but there are no error in the code ,

Comment: @KarthickAnbazhagan is this code, working with you fine   ?

Comment: in your sheet you have fixed Label for Range that is why you are not getting results, try to debug using immediate window,msgbox .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149088/discussion-between-mikz-and-karthick-anbazhagan).

Comment: @KarthickAnbazhagan I am sorry, could you Please join now  ? may be i Need your help to figure it out. what is wrong